# EF Core DatabaseContext for Join Table

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an `Asset` table and a `MixedUseType` table, with a join table of `AssetsMixedUseTypes`. The DBcontext I have for `AssetsMixedUseTypes` works for INSERT and DELETE. But, it doesn't work for UPDATE, and I can't seem to sort what I've configured incorrectly.

**Asset.cs**

```cs
public partial class Asset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public string AssetName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetsMixedUseType>? AssetsMixedUseTypes { get; set; } = new List<AssetsMixedUseType>();
}
```

**MixedUseType.cs**

```cs
public partial class MixedUseType
{
    public int MixedUseTypeId { get; set; }

    public string MixedUseTypeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetsMixedUseType>? AssetsMixedUseTypes { get; set; } = new List<AssetsMixedUseType>();
}
```

**AssetsMixedUseType.cs**

```cs
public partial class AssetsMixedUseType
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public int MixedUseTypeId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Asset? Asset { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual MixedUseType? MixedUseType { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**DatabaseContext.cs**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetsMixedUseType>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(amut => new { amut.AssetId, amut.MixedUseTypeId }).HasName("PK_Mixed_Use_Types");

    entity.ToTable("Assets_Mixed_Use_Types");

    entity.Property(e => e.AssetId).HasColumnName("AssetID");
    entity.Property(e => e.MixedUseTypeId).HasColumnName("MixedUseTypeID");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Asset).WithMany(a => a.AssetsMixedUseTypes)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.AssetId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Assets_Mixed_Use_Types_Assets");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.MixedUseType).WithMany(a => a.AssetsMixedUseTypes)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.MixedUseTypeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Assets_Mixed_Use_Types_Mixed_Use_Types");
});
```

**Edit.cshtml.cs**

```
[BindProperty]
public AssetsMixedUseType AssetsMixedUseType { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, int? assetId)
{
    if (id == null || assetId == null || _context.AssetsMixedUseTypes == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var assetsmixedusetype =  await _context.AssetsMixedUseTypes.Where(m => m.MixedUseTypeId == id).Where(m => m.AssetId == assetId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (assetsmixedusetype == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    AssetsMixedUseType = assetsmixedusetype;
    ViewData["AssetId"] = AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId;
    ViewData["MixedUseTypes"] = new SelectList(_context.MixedUseTypes, nameof(MixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId), nameof(MixedUseType.MixedUseTypeName));
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAssetMixedUseTypeEditAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Attach(AssetsMixedUseType).State = EntityState.Modified;


    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!AssetsMixedUseTypeExists(AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Page();
}
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="AssetMixedUseTypeEdit" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-success="refreshPartial('GetAssetMixedUseTypes', 'MixedUseTypes-container')" data-ajax-failure="ajaxValidationHandler">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId" value="@ViewBag.AssetId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MixedUseTypes"><option disabled selected>- Select Mixed Use Type -</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="javascript:parent.actionPaneClose();">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Aaaaand your update code which "does not work" (how exactly it does not work) is?

Comment: @GuruStron added edit.cshtml.cs to the original post.

Comment: Did you try fetching a single value of `AssetsMixedUseType` using `FirstOrDefault()`, updating properties of that value and see if those change persist in database when you call `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: @Codingwiz that's exactly what's happening here.  At the `_context.Attach(AssetsMixedUseType).State = EntityState.Modified;` line the `AssetsMixedUseType` has new values.

Comment: Maybe its a problem related when attaching the entity or when persisting changes or it might be elsewhere. Is there an error thrown ? Did you debug line by line in your `Edit.cshtml.cs` ?

Comment: How are you fetching and updating `AssetsMixedUseType` before you attach it ?

Comment: @Codingwiz I expanded the original post to include the OnGet and the form.  No error is thrown on `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: The problem may occur when attaching an entity that is a binding property.

Comment: @Codingwiz this same pattern is replicated on 14 other tables/forms in this application/database and the insert/update/delete works in all 14 other instances.  I don't believe the issue is attaching an entity that is a binding property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't tracked the entity at all for no AssetsMixedUseTypes  have the same AssetId & MixedUseTypeId in db, If you track it manully and modify the value:

```
var assetsmixedusetype =  await _context.AssetsMixedUseTypes.Where(m => m.MixedUseTypeId == id).Where(m => m.AssetId == assetId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

......

_context.Entity(AssetsMixedUseType).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You would see an err:

[image]

For you've configured:

```
entity.HasKey(amut => new { amut.AssetId, amut.MixedUseTypeId }).HasName("PK_Mixed_Use_Types");
```

AssetId/MixedUseTypeId are both part of PK of AssetsMixedUseTypes,and entities are tracked by PK

My solution:

just remove the row and add a new row

PageModel:

```
public class EditEntityModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly EFRazorPageContext _context;

        public EditEntityModel(EFRazorPageContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public AssetsMixedUseType AssetsMixedUseType { get; set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty]
        public AssetsMixedUseType FormerEntity { get; set; } = default!;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? assetid,int? mixedusetypeid)
        {
            if (assetid == null || mixedusetypeid==null || _context.AssetsMixedUseType == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var assetsmixedusetype =  await _context.AssetsMixedUseType.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AssetId == assetid && m.MixedUseTypeId== mixedusetypeid);
            if (assetsmixedusetype == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            AssetsMixedUseType = assetsmixedusetype;
            FormerEntity = assetsmixedusetype;
           ViewData["AssetId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Asset>(), "AssetId", "AssetId");
           ViewData["MixedUseTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<MixedUseType>(), "MixedUseTypeId", "MixedUseTypeId");
            return Page();
        }

        
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.AssetsMixedUseType.Remove(FormerEntity);
            _context.AssetsMixedUseType.Add(AssetsMixedUseType);
           

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        
    }
```

Page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FormerEntity.AssetId" hidden/>
                <select asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AssetId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AssetsMixedUseType.AssetId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FormerEntity.MixedUseTypeId" hidden />
                <select asp-for="AssetsMixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MixedUseTypeId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AssetsMixedUseType.MixedUseTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

you could also try write a stored procedure , and then execute it with EFCore

Comment: once again many thanks for the detailed answer! You have been most helpful!!!